# No mostrar Pagina 403 - forbidden: Access is denied - al publicar en IIS

Tags: c#, iis, webapi

Tengo un problema al realizar la publicación de mi proyecto que estoy realizando en **`ANGULAR 8`** y **`C# MVC Web API`** en `IIS`.

La cuestión es que cuando elimino los archivos del servidor **`IIS`**, para poder poner los nuevos con la nueva versión, aparece esta pantalla para los usuarios que están utilizando en la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de que no salga esta pagina o error, y si una pagina la cual yo pueda modificar y agregar estilos a el contenido que yo quiera ?

Gracias de ante mano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ve a la configuración de tu `IIS` y busca **`Sites - > Default -> Error Pages`**, te va a mostrar la lista de errores y la podrás editar.

Espero te ayude, saludos.

Comment: Excelente, pero entonces ahora tengo otras inquietudes, La pagina que tengo que agregar tiene que estar publicada como un sitio de IIS o puede ser una carpeta con la vista y el css ? o como tengo que hacer ?

Comment: El IIS te permite seleccionar la acción a realizar en ese punto; puedes usar una página publicada, un archivo HTML o redireccionar de manera local a cualquier url que necesites.

Comment: Voy a realizar la prueba

Comment: No funciona, agrego la carpeta a la ruta con la vista y sigue saliendo el del sistema

Comment: Tienes un dominio especificado en tu sitio.? En caso de tener un dominio especificado creo que debes aplicarle esa configuración al dominio y no al default ya que esta tomando los parametros del site que configuraste.

Comment: Ps tengo un sitio especifico para el proyecto

Comment: Entonces si el sitio especifico para ese proyecto no tiene los error pages definidos debes definirlos y con eso ya debería funcionar.